# Contar comentarios de un Post (relación polimórfica)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relaciones, polimorfismo

Quiero contar los comentarios que tiene un Post y mi relación es así:

**Post**

```
    public function comment()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Models\CustomComment', 'commentable');
    }
```

**CustomComment**

```
    public function commentable()
    {   
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

Descargué un paquete para Laravel: https://github.com/laravelista/comments

## La vista

Básicamente estoy mostrándo los resultados dentro de mi **dashboard**, dentro de una tabla que me muestra lo siguiente: El título del post, el total (número) de comentarios, para cada post, el último comentario, y una liga que me manda a los comentarios de dicho/cada post.

El *dashboard* tiene 2 métodos y lo necesito simplemente para mostrarme todo lo que existe en mi base de datos, tal vez no sea el dashboard más avanzado pero esto son algunos de los métodos que lo compone:

**HomeController**

```
    public function index()
    {   
        $post = Post::latest()->take(13)->get();
        $category = Category::all();
        $about = About::take(1)->latest()->get();

        return view('/dashboard', [
            'posts' => $post,
            'category' => $category,
            'about' => $about,
            ]);
    }
    
    public function comment_count()
    {
      $count = Post::withCount('comment')->get();
      return view('dashboard.posts', compact('count'));
    }
```

Dentro de mi vista ('dashboard.posts'), estaré implementando un **foreach** en donde mostraré la tabla que mencionaba al principio con los valores que obtenga de mi base de datos.

```
                    <div class="index-content">
                        @foreach ($comments->unique('commentable_id') as $comment)
                            <a class="post-title" 
                                href="/posts/{{ $comment->commentable->slug }}"> 
                                    {{ $comment->commentable->title }}
                            </a>

                            <p class="post-comments">
                                {{ $post->comment }}
                            </p>

                            <p class="post-tags"> 

                            </p>

                            <span class="action-btn">
                                <a class="post-title" 
                                    href="/posts/{{ $comment->commentable->slug }}#comments"> 
                                    <button class="view-btn" id="listModal"> 
                                        <i class="fas fa-eye"></i> 
                                        List
                                    </button>
                                </a>
                            </span>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
```

Debajo del elemento **p class="post-comments"** es en donde me gustaría contar los comentarios que un Post tiene. No he podido realizar lo anterior.

Como referencia anexo una consulta SQL que me gustaría fuera el equivalente dentro de mi controlador y poder usado en mi vista, dado que esta es una relación polimórfica se me complica entender el tema.

```
select count(commentable_id)
from comments
where commentable_id = 'id';
```

Como se puede observar, deseo encontrar el id para cualquier post y que me traiga el numero de comentarios que tiene cada uno y mostrarlo en una vista. Como no esperaba trabajar con relaciones polimórficas se me ha salido un poco de alcance ya que no conozco mucho acerca del tema.

Comment: Porfavor vuelve a leer la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución. El problema está que no hay necesidad de comenzar el **@foreach** con la variable de **comments**, si no con **posts** ya que podemos accesar mediante nuestra relación a las columnas de la tabla de **Comments**. Entonces al querer contar lo hice de esta manera:

```
@foreach ($posts->sortByDesc('created_at') as $post)
                            @if($post->is_approved == 1)
                                <a class="post-title"
                                    href="/posts/{{ $post->slug }}"> 
                                        {{ $post->title }}
                                </a>

                                <p class="post-category">
                                    {{  $post->comments->count() }}
                                </p>

                                <p class="post-tags"> 
                                    {{ $post->created_at->format("m/d/Y") }}
                                </p>

                                <span class="action-btn">
                                    <a class="post-title" 
                                        href="/posts/{{ $post->slug }}#comments"> 
                                        <button class="view-btn" id="listModal"> 
                                            <i class="fas fa-eye"></i> 
                                            List
                                        </button>
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                            @endif 
                        @endforeach
```

Y para cada post se contaron los comentarios, incluyendo los comentarios con respuesta. Si quisieramos no incluir esos comentarios que tienen una respuesta, el conteo se tendría que aplicar de la siguiente manera:

```
{{ $post->comments->where('child_id', '')->count() }}
```

La columna *child_id* es la responsable de guardar cualquier réplica para algún comentario. En este caso por eso se necesita de una relación polimórfica, porque un comentario es algo que también se puede comentar, al igual que un **Post** es algo "comentable".

Answer (score 4):

Comentarios:

1. No estás trabajando con una relación de muchos a muchos (*yo no noto tabla intermedia alguna*) como colocas en tu pregunta, es una relación [**uno a muchos**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)
2. La consulta que te devolvería los posts y el conteo de comentarios que cada uno de estos tiene es la siguiente:

   ```
   $count = Post::withCount('comments')->get();
   ```

Aquí vamos a aclarar que te esta fallando con el mensaje de: *SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'comments.post_id' in* por que la llave foránea en tu entidad *CustomComment* no se corresponde en nombre al esperado por *Eloquent*

De la propia documentación extraigo y cito<sup>1</sup>:

> Remember, Eloquent will automatically determine the proper foreign key column for the Comment model. By convention, Eloquent will take the "snake case" name of the parent model and suffix it with _id. So, in this example, Eloquent will assume the foreign key column on the Comment model is post_id.

Que se puede traducir(mas o menos) como:

> Recuerda, Eloquent automáticamente determinará la llave foránea adecuada para el modelo Comment. Por convención, Eloquent tomará el nombre tipo *snake case* del modelo padre y le agregará como sufijo el `_id`. Así que, en este ejemplo, Eloquent asumirá que la columna de llave foránea en el modelo Comment es `post_id`

Dado lo anterior, entonces recomiendo leas a detalle la sintaxis que debes seguir [indicada por la propia doc.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) y hagas los cambios necesarios<sup>1</sup>

3. Esta consulta que tienes:

   ```
   $comment = Post::withCount('commentable_id')->get();
   ```

Es errónea, pues como puedes apreciar en la propia [doc. al respecto](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) nos muestra que el argumento que se debe pasar es el nombre de la relación

4. Esta forma de tratar de imprimir el conteo **`{{ $comment_count }}`** también es errónea pues efectivamente no existe variable alguna con dicho nombre, ya que `comment_count` es de hecho una propiedad.
5. Por otro lado si a parte del conteo de comentarios quieres además que se incluyan los comentarios asociados a cada uno de los posts, entonces tu consulta se debe parecer a esto:

   ```
   $postsWithComments = Post::withCount('comments')->with('comments')->get();
   ```
6. Si lo que quieres es el conteo de publicaciones de un post específico como tu mismo expones en la consulta SQL mostrada, entonces es tal simple como esto:

   ```
   $postWithCountComments = Post::withCount('comments')->findOrFail($idPost);
   ```

Comment: Cuál es la diferencia entre el punto 3 y 5? el 3 sólo incluye el comentario + el conteo? el punto 5 regresa: el post, el comentario y el conteo de comentarios? la diferencia sería en la asociación de posts y comentarios? que es lo que no trae el punto 3. quiere decir que también puedo accesar a las propiedades del post?  Me parece bien tu respuesta, aunque en la vista me regresa el conteo para solo un post. Incluyo ambas queries, del punto 5 y 3 y en la vista pongo esto: ```{{ $post->comments->count() }}``` gracias. en el modelo que busca la columna, le agrego "commentable_id"

Comment: Veo que asumes que estoy utilizando este: ```$postWithCountComments = Post::withCount('comments')->findOrFail($idPost);``` y me sugieres que use este: ```$count = Post::withCount('comment')->get();``` que es escencialmente lo mismo pero al final no lleva el **findOrFail()** Y que en mi foreach utilize esto: ```{{ $posts->comment }} ```

Comment: Resultado: ```{"id":3,"commenter_id":null,"commenter_type":null,"guest_name":"warpig","guest_email":"eduardongua@hotmail.com","commentable_type":"App\\Models\\Post","commentable_id":"9","comment":"message as guest","approved":1,"child_id":null,"deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2021-02-03T15:56:00.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-02-03T15:56:00.000000Z"} ```

Comment: Ya quedo. Gracias por participar.

Comment: Me refiero a que ya quedo editada la pregunta, seguiré investigando